# SQL statement that shows at least 16 courses not taken

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have four schemas:

```
takes(ID,course_id,sec_id,semester,year)
student(ID,name,dept_name,tot_credit)
course(course_id,title,dept_name,credits)
department(dept_name,building,budget)
```

I want to create a query that finds the name and id of each Astronomy student whose name begins with the letter ’T’ and who has not taken at least 16 Astronomy courses.

What's the easiest way I could do this?

I already wrote this beginning bit

```
SELECT name, id
FROM student
WHERE dept_name='Astronomy' AND name LIKE '%T%'
```

I'm not quite sure how to finish this off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's the result

```
NAME                 ID    CLASS_TAKEN
-------------------- ----- -----------
Tolle                38279          12 
Teo                  62268          13 
Tolle                93223          13 
Tsukamoto            17707           5 
Titi                 11576           9 
Teo                  91772          12 
Toraichi             50387          11 
Tewari               80754          14 
Tiroz                64091          14 

 9 rows selected
```

I need Teo with the id 91772 and Tewari 80754 to be gone

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you post some example data, and an explanation about any relationships between the tables?

Comment: NAME ID
-------------------- -----
Tim 62268
Timothy 64091
Titi 11576
Tolle 93223
Tolle 38279
Toraichi 50387
Tsukamoto 17707

Comment: My bad, I should've realized

Comment: There is no possible way that the query shown in this question (with two expression in the SELECT list) would return a resultset with three columns. There is no reference to a column (or expression) aliased as `CLASS_TAKEN` in the query, or in the `student` table. This question cries out for some stepwise refinement: 1) get a list of students, then 2) get a list of students along with any astronomy classes they've taken. From the specification ("who has not taken at least 16 Astronomy courses"), and the sample data, it doesn't make sense that either Teo 91772 and Tewari 80754 would be "gone".

Answer (score 1):

Given my reading of the requirements and the comments it's pretty clear that the question is not very clear. :-) What you're looking for are students where (total # of courses given by the Astronomy department) - (# of Astronomy courses taken by student) >= 16. So, how do we find these values? First, let's start with the total number of courses given by the Astronomy department. This is pretty simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ASTRONOMY_COURSE_COUNT
  FROM COURSE
  WHERE DEPT_NAME = 'ASTRONOMY'
```

Now, the second part is to determine how many courses given by the Astronomy department each student has taken. To do this we need to start with the student, join to the courses the student has taken (the TAKES table), then join to the COURSES table to find out which department each course is part of. Something like the following should do it:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.NAME, COUNT(*) AS STUDENT_ASTRO_COUNT
  FROM STUDENT s
  INNER JOIN TAKES t
    ON t.ID = s.ID
  INNER JOIN COURSE c
    ON c.COURSE_ID = t.COURSE_ID
  WHERE c.DEPT_NAME = 'ASTRONOMY' AND
        s.NAME LIKE 'T%'
  GROUP BY s.ID, s.NAME;
```

OK, now we need to put this together. You've tagged this question for both Oracle and MySQL so I'm going to guess you'll accept valid syntax for either database; thus I'll use Oracle Common Table Expression syntax to pull everything together:

```
WITH ASTRONOMY_COURSES AS (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ASTRONOMY_COURSE_COUNT
                             FROM COURSE
                             WHERE DEPT_NAME = 'ASTRONOMY'),
     STUDENT_ASTRO_COURSES AS (SELECT s.ID,
                                      s.NAME,
                                      COUNT(*) AS STUDENT_ASTRO_COUNT
                                 FROM STUDENT s
                                 INNER JOIN TAKES t
                                   ON t.ID = s.ID
                                 INNER JOIN COURSE c
                                   ON c.COURSE_ID = t.COURSE_ID
                                 WHERE c.DEPT_NAME = 'ASTRONOMY' AND
                                       s.NAME LIKE 'T%'
                                 GROUP BY ID)
SELECT s.ID,
       s.NAME,
       s.STUDENT_ASTRO_COUNT,
       a.ASTRONOMY_COURSE_COUNT - s.STUDENT_ASTRO_COUNT AS UNTAKEN_COUNT
  FROM STUDENT_ASTRO_COURSES s
  CROSS JOIN ASTRONOMY_COURSES a
  WHERE a.ASTRONOMY_COURSE_COUNT - s.STUDENT_ASTRO_COUNT >= 16;
```

Note here that a CROSS JOIN is used to put together the subqueries. This means that all the rows of each subquery are joined to all the rows of the other subquery - but since in this case the ASTRONOMY_COURSES subquery will only return a single row what we're doing is appending the ASTRONOMY_COURSE_COUNT value onto each row returned by the STUDENT_ASTRO_COURSES subquery.

That should at least get you pretty close. Amend as needed.

Not tested on animals - you'll be first! :-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I concur with the assessment of the specification. One note: we should at least consider the possibility that there may be students with `dept_name='Astronomy'` who has not yet taken *any* Astronomy courses. (We could assume that the query should return only students that have taken at least one Astronomy course, but that's an assumption; a more liberal reading of the specification would *include* those students.)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will need to reference more tables than just the `student` table.

Your tables seem be missing some important information, which `student` has taken which `course`. There's a table named `takes`, but there doesn't appear to be any relationship between `takes` and `student`.

So first, figure out how to list the students along with the Astronomy courses they have taken. Each row will identify the `student` and a `course`.

```
SELECT s.id     AS student_id
     , s.name   AS student_name
     , t.???
  FROM student s
  JOIN ??? t
    ON t.student_id = s.id
 WHERE ...
```

You may also need to include another "join" to an additional table, in order to identify which course a student has taken is an Astronomy course.

To also include students that have not take *any* Astronomy courses, you can use an outer join, rather than an inner join.  (That would mean including the `LEFT` keyword before `JOIN`, and relocating predicates from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.  (A predicate in the `WHERE` clause that can only be satisfied by non-NULL values will negate the *outer*-ness of the join.)

Once you have a query that returns that set (students along with any astronomy courses they've taken), you can then add a `GROUP BY` clause to "collapse" a set of rows into a single row. (Looks like you want the rows "grouped" by student.)

And then an aggregate function like `COUNT()` or `SUM()` can be used to get a count of rows for each group. (If you don't want to count any re-takes of a course (a "duplicate" course for a student) you may be able to make use of the `COUNT(DISTINCT t.foo)` form.

And then a `HAVING` clause can be added to the query, to compare the value returned from the aggregate expression to a constant value, to return only rows that satisfy a specific condition.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Assuming:

```
CREATE TABLE course
( id         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK'
, title      VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'course title'
, dept_name  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref dept.name'
, credits    DECIMAL(5,2)          COMMENT 'credit hours'
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE student
( id         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'PK'
, name       VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'student name'
, dept_name  VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref dept.name'
, tot_credit INT                   COMMENT '?'
, PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE takes
( student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref student.id'
, course_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref course.id'
, sec_id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '?'
, semester   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '?'
, year       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '?'
, PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
, CONSTRAINT FK_takes_course FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course (id)
, CONSTRAINT FK_takes_student FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (id)
);
```

Query to get a list of students...

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.name
  FROM student s
 WHERE s.name LIKE 'T%'
   AND s.dept_name = 'ASTRONOMY'
```

Get list of students along with the courses they've taken, returning the id of the ASTRONOMY courses they've taken...

```
SELECT s.id     AS student_id
     , s.name   AS student_name
     , c.id     AS course_id
  FROM student s
  LEFT
  JOIN takes t
    ON t.student_id = t.id
  LEFT
  JOIN course c
    ON c.id = t.course_id
   AND c.dept_name = 'ASTRONOMY'
 WHERE s.name LIKE 'T%'
   AND s.dept_name = 'ASTRONOMY'
```

Collapse the rows to one per student using a `GROUP BY`, and use aggregate functions to get counts or totals.

```
SELECT s.id                  AS student_id
     , s.name                AS student_name
     , SUM(c.credits)        AS total_astronomy_credits_taken
     , COUNT(c.id)           AS count_astronomy_courses_taken
     , COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)  AS count_distinct_astronomy_courses_taken
  FROM student s
  LEFT
  JOIN takes t
    ON t.student_id = t.id
  LEFT
  JOIN course c
    ON c.id = t.course_id
   AND c.dept_name = 'ASTRONOMY'
 WHERE s.name LIKE 'T%'
   AND s.dept_name = 'ASTRONOMY'
 GROUP
    BY s.id
     , s.name
```

To omit rows from this resultset, add a `HAVING` clause. For example, to exclude rows where total_astronomy_credits_taken is greater than or equal to 12...

```
HAVING total_astronomy_credits_taken >= 12
```

If you want the rows returned in a certain sequence, specify that in an `ORDER BY` clause

```
 ORDER BY s.id
```

If you want to replace NULL values from the aggregates with zeroes, you can warp the aggregate expression in an `IFNULL(foo,0)` function, e.g.

```
     , IFNULL(COUNT(c.id),0)    AS count_astronomy_courses_taken
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use all tables?

Table `department` has no links with the student,
Table `takes` has no links with the student,
Table `course`has no links with the student.
If student lists total credits that are all Astronomy I think this can be used:

```
select name, id, MAX(tot_credit) as credits
from student
where dept_name='Astronomy' and name like 'T%'
group by name, id
having MAX(tot_credit)<=16
```

PS -  you schema is not good; PK-FK references are missing

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
select a.name, a.id, count(b.ID) as class_taken   
from student a inner join takes b
on a.ID = b.ID
inner join course c
on b.course_id = c.course_id   
where a.dept_name='Astronomy' and substring(a.name,1,1) = 'T'
group by a.name, a.id
having count(b.ID) < 17
```

Comment: I'm getting an output of 9 rows of data which is two more rows than I need.

Comment: maybe `having count(b.ID) < 16` ? can you edit your question and give me the result and which data you want to eliminated?

Comment: I'm getting an incorrect output of 9 rows which is two more than what is suppossed to happen.

Comment: Sorry the comments didn't pop up so I re-entered it again

Comment: Ok, give me the result somewhere maybe in pastebin, and tell me that 9 rows?

Comment: Teo with the id 91772 and Tewari 80754 has lower than 16 courses, why you want to remove them?

Comment: I just edited the question like you wanted. Not sure what pastebin is, I don't get on stackoverflow a lot. Also, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it

Comment: Both Teo and Tewari have courses lower than 16, why you want to remove them?

Comment: I'm supposed to find the students who still need to take 16 courses. The output I posted is the correct output, I just am having trouble getting said output

Comment: I mean why you want to remove them while they just have 12 and 14 courses. What criteria for removing them?

Comment: Here's the explanation I was given "For example, say T1 has taken 15 courses in Astronomy and there are a total of 17 courses. T1 has only NOT taken 2 courses in Astronomy. Therefore he would not be included" He has to have not taken at least 16 courses. This phrase is why I'm so confused

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that query and result. They just has taken 12 and 14 courses. Is this your homework? Read it carefully, maybe you missing something.